# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp (line: 60, column: 149) equal symbol expected

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

can you please help me to solve this?? 
Here is my jsp:

**Required Field**

```
                <div class="input-group">
                    <form:input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" path="username" placeholder="Enter Name" required />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <form:input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" path="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required/>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <form:input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="pass" path="pass" name="pass" required/>

                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right"/>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

and  I get error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp (line: 60, column: 149) equal symbol expected
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:91)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:218)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:163)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:154)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1231)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1455)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1668)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:996)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1271)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1455)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
>       org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Which one is line 60?

Comment: Line 60 is   <form:input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" path="username" placeholder="Enter Name" required />

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
required
```

by

```
required="required"
```

Answer (score -2):

In a jsp file, when we include attributes like enabled, required, readonly etc. those should be used inside the  tag as enabled="enabled"
required="required" , readonly="readonly" etc.

I solved a similar issue using the same method